# How Do I Repair this Door Damage?

Tags: doors, wood-filler

The previous owner apparently hacked out a piece of the door. How should I fix it? If I use wood filler, what's the best way to mold it so that it's square? Is there a better fix? (I don't want to replace the door.)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Someone tried cutting your door with a sawz-all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that is correct. No guide. Full blast. No control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is an interior door, I'd just scribe the top of the door parallel with the top of the jamb and plane it to the line.  It actually looks a tad out of square and a bit tight in the jamb.

Comment: Agree with @Comintern. They probably cut it because the door was sticking Plane could square up the mess so it did not look so bad. I think wood filler would get chipped off.

Comment: Yes to setting a line and cutting nice and straight, but check the reveal on the hinge side first. If it's narrow at the bottom and wide at the top, then the door is probably binding across the head. Remove material until it doesn't bind (and possibly use a long screw in one of the hinge holes to make the hinge-side reveal correct). Once the door moves freely, you can make a perfect line and cut to it. (And though it's conventional to have a small gap at the top, a slightly bigger gap is acceptable. It should be even, though.)

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for the reply. It is an interior door in a 50 yr old house. It's definitely out of square. It binds on the top of the knob side and has a 1/8th reveal at the bottom of the knob side.

Answer (score 1):

Strike a line from the low edge (on the knob side) the same depth to the hinge side. It looks to be about 1/4 inch? Using whatever power tools available remove the top section following the pencil mark. (circular saw, planer, or belt sander will help with removal).

The standard door gaps are as follows: 1/16th inch at the top, 1/8th inch on both sides. If the gap is not acceptable or too large you may have to lower the door molding.